# How can I get a range from negative infinity to infinity to be represented in a range from 0 to 1?

Tags: c++

Sorry, hard to explain. How can I get any number to be represented as a number 0 to 1 for my AI? I am trying to get a set of data to be a binary number to make a decision based off of it.

This is for my first AI, I tried making an average based on the min/max, but decided that an exponential function would be better.

I just want something that would round to a 0 or 1 so that my AI can make decisions.

Comment: I think this is more a question of math than of programming.  You want a convenient bijection from [-oo, +oo] to [0,1].  Try http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It seems that the number 0 sits at the exact midpoint between negative and positive infinity. Therefore, in your proposed mapping, every negative value will round to 0, and every positive value will round to 1, so why simply skip the middle man? The biggest decision here, it seems, is to decide which way 0 goes.

Comment: Look at Riemann numbers. You map the numbers through a circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the sigmoid function, `1 / (1 + exp(-x))`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function